# Инсталлятор, который запускает другой инсталлятор

Tags: c#, windowsinstaller

Доброго времени суток.
Ситуация следующая, мне нужно создать инсталлятор, который помимо самой установки запускает еще один инсталлятор. И он его таки запускает, но в процессе вылазит ошибка "Another installation already running". 
Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: А причём тут C# к вашему вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов решения:

1. Если требуется именно msi, то можно запускать дочернюю установку до основной фазы родительской, с помощью Custom Action'ов. Минус - rollback не будет удалять другую установку.
2. Если можно использовать exe, то Windows Installer Вам уже не нужен, просто необходимо будет [зарегистрировать компоненты тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx), самостоятельно скопировать данные из ресурсов в нужные папки, самостоятельно нарисовать UI. По времени это будет намного быстрее, чем разбираться с msi (так делает JetBrains, Microsoft, Oracle и многие другие).
3. Грязный хак: два msi внутри exe, который внутри msi. Схема проста: msi запускает Custom Action в самом начале, который убивает родительский процесс, устанавливает первый продукт, а потом устанавливает второй. Это нужно только в случаях, где обязательно требуется Windows Installer (например, если заказчик так хочет).